# How to get the sequence of execution of batch jobs included in installed package

Tags: managed-package, metadata, package, salesforce-data-mask

Which component or class will tell the sequence of execution of batch jobs included in installed package(data mask).
There are multiple batch jobs in installed package. I want to know in which sequence they run.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that the developer of a package only controls when the batch is initially queued; it is entirely up to the Salesforce platform to decide just when the batch `start`, `execute` and `finish` methods are actually called. There isn't even a guarantee that execute is called "in order" for the batch chunks. That said, you can guarantee, on a given org:

1. Only one batch `start` is called at a time
2. Only up to 5 batches execute at the same time
3. Only 100 batches can be on hold in the flex queue, waiting to run
4. A batch has `start` called and this is the first method invoked
5. A batch has `execute` called 0 or more times with the chunks of records to be processed
6. The `finish` method is called last

Debug logs can hint at what was executed when, though may not have the fine-grained timing info to be entirely sure of sequencing of concurrent executions.

Answer (score 0):

There's not any way to tell, necessarily. You can check the debug logs in Setup, but this may or may not show any useful information. The developer of the package determines the order in which code will run, so you must reach out to their support team to find out.